# What is this group.com.apple.PegasusConfiguration folder used for?

Tags: macos

In the folder Group Containers and Application Scripts is a folder named **group.com.apple.PegasusConfiguration**.

Does anybody know what the use of this folder is? Is it really from Apple? I didn't find any useful information about this service/folder but does Apple really name a folder after a legendary iOS spyware?